# The > at end of a TableViewCell not showing up

Tags: ios7

Screenshot of the app screenshot is at https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1PZ4somNxNtVk12M2dBbi16dHM&authuser=0 (I am not allowed to post images directly!).  As seen in the screenshot the ">" that is typically present at the end of a table view cell is not showing up.  What do I need to do to make it show up?

Comment: this link asks for access permission!

Comment: bdw, typical ">" will not come by default. i guess you have to set respective accessory view for that

Comment: Thanks BaSha, could you tell me how to set this accessory view?

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking accessory type in storyboard Accessory to DisclosureIndicator.

```
[cellInstance setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
```